# Filtering LinkingObjects of a LinkingObject in a predicate in RealmSwift

Tags: swift, realm

Given the following example realm classes:

**Car**

```
class Car: Object {
   dynamic var make = ""
   let owner = List<Person>()
}
```

**Person**

```
class Person: Object {
   dynamic var name = “”
   dynamic var age = 0
   let children = List<Person>()
   let dad = LinkingObjects(fromType: Person.self, property: "children")
   let cars = LinkingObjects(fromType: Car.self, property: "owner")
}
```

I'd like to get the people whose dad drives a Mustang (using a predicate).

I would think of a predicate like this one:

```
 "(ANY dad[FIRST].cars.make  == Mustang)"
```

But `[FIRST]` is not supported yet.

Is there a another way to achieve this in just one predicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find people whose father drives a mustang, you can use a predicate like so:

```
realm.objects(Person.self).filter("ANY dad.cars.make = 'Mustang'")
```

Comment: I can't edit that, but surely the object path in the filter should read 'dad.cars.make' ?